# Como adicionar uma classe no formulário após o retorno da página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um input do tipo hidden que recebe o nome do menu que foi selecionado que foi retornando da aplicação, ele pode receber (andamentos, encerramento, valores) 
Após o retorno do post, quero que o menu que foi recebido no input fique ativo (class="tab-pane fade active"
Tenho o meu formulário :

```
    <script>


                function AdicionarClasseMenuSelecionado(){
                    var menuatual = document.getElementById('MenuSelecionado').value;
                        alert(menuatual);

                        //remove todos os active
                        $("#aba1").removeClass("active");
                        $("#aba2").removeClass("active");
                        $("#aba3").removeClass("active");

                        //adiciona o active de acordo com o input
                        $("#andamentos").addClass("active in");
                        $("#aba2").addClass("active");
                    }



    </script>
```

---

```
      <div class="container">


                        <button type="button" onclick="AdicionarClasseMenuSelecionado()" class="btn btn-default">Teste</button>

                        <input name="MenuSelecionado" type="hidden"  value="andamentos" id="MenuSelecionado">


                        <form action="#" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <legend>Cadastro Teste</legend>
                                </div>

                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                          <li class="active" id="aba1"><a data-toggle="tab"    href="#encerramento">Encerramento</a></li>
                          <li id="aba2"><a data-toggle="tab"  href="#andamentos">Andamentos</a></li>
                          <li id="aba3"><a data-toggle="tab"   href="#valores">Valores</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="tab-content">

                          <div id="encerramento" class="tab-pane fade active">
                            <h3>Encerramento</h3>
                            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                          </div>

                          <div id="andamentos" class="tab-pane fade ">
                            <h3>Andamentos</h3>
                            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
                          </div>

                          <div id="valores" class="tab-pane fade ">
                            <h3>Valores</h3>
                            <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
                          </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                       </form>

                  </div>
```

Comment: Ele volta para a inicial pq após o envio do form a página recarrega, aí volta para a aba inicial.

Comment: Pode postar o código para que possamos fazer testes e achar uma solução?

Comment: Pode depois de fazer post no formulário pode colocar a classe .active na aba que lhe interessa quanto está a construir a página do lado servidor.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, eu adicionei o codigo hmtl com um formulário, apos o post, quero manter a mesma aba aberta

Comment: @JorgeCosta, como eu posso retornar o formulário com a mesma aba aberta? agradeço

Comment: Qual a a linguagem do lado servidor

Comment: @JorgeCosta, asp.net webformes,

Comment: Pode postar o código

Comment: @JorgeCosta, postei o código, basicamente ele faz apenas a gravação do formulário

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, Simplifiquei a minha pergunta, veja, eu recebo um conteúdo no meu input, quero que o menu receba a classe de acordo com o que estou recebendo neste input

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, o codigo a cima funciona, eu consigo adicionar a classe onde preciso, mais queria adicionar a classe de forma dinâmica

Answer (score 0):

Sua função ficará dinâmica desta forma:

```
function AdicionarClasseMenuSelecionado(){
   var menuatual = document.getElementById('MenuSelecionado').value;
   alert(menuatual);

   //remove todos os active
   $("ul.nav-tabs li").removeClass("active");

   //adiciona o active de acordo com o input
   $("#"+menuatual).addClass("active in");
   $("ul.nav-tabs li a[href='#"+menuatual+"']").addClass("active");
}
```

Aqui `$("ul.nav-tabs li").removeClass("active");` você remove a classe de todos os `<li>` de uma só vez.

Aqui `$("#"+menuatual).addClass("active in");` você adiciona a classe ao elemento que tem o `id` igual ao valor do `input`, apenas concatenando o símbolo `#` antes para selecionar o elemento.

Aqui `$("ul.nav-tabs li a[href='#"+menuatual+"']").addClass("active");` você adiciona a classe ao elemento `<a>` que possui o atributo `href` igual ao valor do `input`, também concatenando o símbolo `#`.